# Adding rows to a data grid view using a form C#

Tags: c#, forms, object, grid

How can I add rows to a data grid view using a separate form? When I'm trying to pass it like this

```
        private void btnDodajPrzychod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formMain.gridPrzychody.Rows.Add("123");
        this.Close();
    }
```

it says that an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property "formMain.gridPrzychody".

How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

When you calling the new Form, you must pass a handler to access the gridView from previous form. the handler could be the first form object or the gridview object. 
for example:

```
FormNew fm = new FormNew(this.gridPrzychody);
```

then in the new form get and store the handler. when ever you want, you can use it then.

```
GridView gridView;
public FormNew(GridView gridView)
{
   this.gridView = gridView;
}
```